# Marketo Forms / Tridion integration

Tags: 2013-sp1, external-integrations

Does anyone have any experience integrating Marketo Forms with Tridion?

I have found a Javascript include that pulls a form in. Though I would like to hear about  others approach to the following areas.

- Publishing
- Styling
- Localisation / Translation

Any tips much appreciated, especially on the translation side.

Thanks
Mark

Comment: I'm not familiar with Marketo Forms yet, but could offer suggestions if you could share what the Javascript include needs and/or describe Marketo's content model and/or markup. Tridion Translation would only apply for elements managed in Tridion, really. Otherwise you're looking at a "labels" type setup where you provide the text to the integration in a file, page's markup, or via API/database.

Comment: Hi Alvin, You can find the Marketo API reference here http://developers.marketo.com/documentation/websites/forms-2-0/ . Thanks for your interest. I am working up a Javascript demo though I am not convinced it is the answer. Using labels published from Tridion as JSON.

Comment: The JavaScript embed fits ECL (like in Bart's answer) or a Schema field (like on sdl.com per joostcom) that points to the Marketo form. If the Marketo API can replace labels with their translated versions, it might work, but it looks like separate forms might be a better (less hackish) fit.

Answer (score 9):

The sdl.com corporate website has an integration with Marketo. Here are some details from a functional point of view:

**Integration**
Marketo forms are presented on the Tridion webpage in an iframe. The form is created in Marketo, which results in a Marketo form url. With a manual action the Marketo form url is added to a Tridion form component. This component can be linked to an event page or a download page by users.

**Publishing**
When the Marketo form url is introduced to the Tridion environment, the form component need to be published. The form will be presented on every event page or download page that is published.

**Form styling**
When using an iframe to present the Marketo form, all form styling need to be applied in the  Marketo form builder (I believe there is a 2.0 version), but it has limited styling options and form field functionality.

**Translation / localization**
Each form component holds one Marketo form url for a specific language. Supporting ten languages requires localization of the form fields and submit button and the creation of ten forms in Marketo. This will deliver ten Markto form urls. In Tridion the parent form component will be localized in all the local content publications. The local components will have the language specific Marketo form url. The result is that the Japanese download page will have the Japanese Marketo form presented in the iframe without additional handling by the user.

Comment: Thanks. It is great to know how Tridion approached it on there site. Really helpful

Answer (score 4):

I don't have experience with Marketo myself, but I did create an ECL provider for Wufoo once, and its code could most likely be used as an example of how you can do the same with Marketo.

Basically I used ECL since it gives us a good framework to connect external content providers. All that is required is that Marketo has an API that you can connect to, so you can list the forms you have and then you need a way to embed them (which there currently already is). The publishing part is something I would say is then done from Tridion, if your Marketo form also needs to be published at the same time, you will want to investigate the `Dispatch()` method, here you can implement stuff you need to call on the Marketo side.

You can read all about my ECL provider in the blogpost here http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/forms-without-java-xslt-or-even-xml and download it for free  on SDL Tridion World http://sdltridionworld.com/community/2011_extensions/wufoo_ecl_provider.aspx. It comes with full (open) source, so you should have everything to get started. If this is the first ECL provider you are creating, you will most likely have some further questions, these you can of course ask here again.

For the localization/translation part I think I should direct to towards another blog post of mine http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/ecl-and-blueprinting. How easy that is to accomplish all depends on how well you can map the SDL Tridion BluePrinting concept to Marketo.

Comment: Great thinking. I will look into what Marketo offers in terms of Web serivces.

Answer (score 3):

The [Default Schemas for Tridion](https://github.com/paceaux/Default-Schemas-for-Tridion) has form schemas that can be used for creating forms. The schemas make use of repeatable component links and embeddable schemas that allow you make a 'field' that's a component, and can therefore be localized or reused in many different kinds of forms.

Answer (score 3):

Check this Blog Post where I am describing how to make an Embedded Forms integration

[SDL Tridion - Marketo Forms Integration](https://community.rws.com/product-groups/tridion/tridion-sites/b/techweblog/posts/sdl-tridion-and-marketo-forms-integratoin)